# I can't figure out what's wrong with this statement. $wpdb->query update

Tags: sql, wordpress

I'm trying to use the $wpdb-query method, but can't seem to get it to work.

I get a 500 error when I try the following:

```
$update_status = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}wcpv_commissions SET commission_status = '".$status."' WHERE vendor_id = '".$vendor_id."' AND order_date BETWEEN '".$date1."' AND '".$date2."'"));
```

Is there something I am missing here. I have not used $wpdb much, so am sure I must be missing something.

I appreciate any help here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[$wpdb::prepare()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) expects two parameters, and you're only providing one (which, if it even worked as is, is open to SQL Injection attacks).

You need to pass your variables in an array as the second parameter for `prepare()` to work:

```
$update_status = $wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}wcpv_commissions SET commission_status = %s WHERE vendor_id = %d AND order_date BETWEEN %s AND %s",
        array($status, $vendor_id, $date1, $date2)
    )
);
```

Notice the usage of the placeholders `%s` and `%d`, they're important: the former will be replaced by a string, the latter by a digit.

Comment: Also, it might be a good idea to [enable the debug log](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) while writing code. It'll help you spot and understand errors faster.